# How to save a 3D array in python and Import it in mathematica

Tags: python-2.7, 3d, save, wolfram-mathematica

I want to save a 3D binary array in .txt file or .csv file on python and import it onto mathematica.

I googled  and I found a lot of answers, I try this:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.zeros((2,3,4))
a[0,0,0]=10
cPickle.dump( a, open( "matrix.txt", "wb" ) )
```

In mathematica I have used the Import["matrix.txt","Data"] and I did not get what I expect

```
IN[]:Import["matrix.txt", "Data"]

  Out[]:{{"cnumpy.core.multiarray"}, {"_reconstruct"}, {"p1"}, {"(cnumpy"}, \
    {"ndarray"}, {"p2"}, {"(I0"}, {"tS'b'"}, {"tRp3"}, {"(I1"}, {"(I2"}, \
    {"I3"}, {"I4"}, {"tcnumpy"}, {"dtype"}, {"p4"}, {"(S'f8'"}, {"I0"}, \
    {"I1"}, {"tRp5"}, {"(I3"}, {"S'<'"}, {"NNNI-1"}, {"I-1"}, {"I0"}, \
    {"tbI00"}, \
    {"S'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00$@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\\
    x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\\
    x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\\
    x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\\
    x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\\
    x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\\
    x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\\
    x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\\
    x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\\
    x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\\
    x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\\
    x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\\
    x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\\
    x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'"}, {"tb."}}
```

Comment: Um, Can you define what you were excepting?

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit, I have to get the value of the saved matrix!

Answer (score 7):

The trick is to flatten the array as a 2D-array :

```
import numpy as np
a=np.zeros((2,3,4))
a[0,0,0]=10
b=a.reshape(1,24)

np.savetxt("/matrix.CSV",b,delimiter=',')
```

and then convert it in 3D in Mathematica after importing, we can use:

```
 file=Import["matrix.CSV","Data"]
 matrix=ArrayReshape[file, {2, 3, 4}]
```

Comment: Congratulations for answering your own question and thanks for having posted it !